# What is a non-trivial covering space?

Tags: algebraic-topology, definition

I've come across this term many times but its meaning seems to be always assumed. Sometimes it looks like it means the covering space is connected or path-connected sometimes just that it is not equal to the space $X$ being covered. So what is exact definition? thanks

Comment: In fact, there are two non-equivalent notions of trivial covering spaces, both are used in the literature. One is spelled out in Lee Mosher's answer. The other is that a trivial covering (over a connected space $B$) is a trivial fiber bundle $E\to B$ with discrete fibers. In other words, $E=B\times F$, with $F$ a discrete space and $p: E\to B$ the projection to the first factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To say that $X$ is a nontrivial covering space of $Y$ means that there exists a covering map $f : X \to Y$ such that $f$ is not a homeomorphism, equivalently $f$ is not one-to-one, equivalently the degree of $f$ is $\ge 2$ (recall that the degree is the cardinality of any fiber $f^{-1}(y)$, which is well-defined independent of $y \in Y$).

As a complement to this, one might say that $X$ is a trivial covering space of $Y$ if there exists a homeomorphism $f : X \to Y$. 
Any space is a trivial covering space of any space to which it is homeomorphic. In particular, every space is a trivial covering space of itself.

But, it is quite possible for a space to *also* be a nontrivial covering space of itself. For example, $S^1$ is a nontrivial covering space of itself in many different ways, meaning that there exist covering maps of any degree $n \ge 2$: using complex coordinates, take the map $f(z)=z^n$. More generally, the $k$-dimensional torus $$T^k = \underbrace{S^1 \times \cdots \times S^1}_{\text{$k$ times}}
$$
is also a nontrivial covering space of itself.

Comment: very clear, thank you!